# Создание дампа mysql

Tags: mysql, dump

Работаю на денвере через CMD (Денвер потому что весит мало), есть несколько вопросов по Mysql.

1. Как создать дамп БД "pochta", в гугле встретил запросы но они работают только на линуксе.
2. Как сделать автоматическое создание дампа в директорию c:\ каждый день в 2 часа ночи.
3. Как реализовать запрос "Source comand.sql" в отдельный comand.bat

Comment: `Как создать дамп БД "pochta", в гугле встретил запросы но они работают только на линуксе.`  - вы же третьим пунктом написали `source`  .... оно работает и на windows. Вы не пробовали? ...... 2 пункт - нужен CRON  (планировщик задач)

Comment: Когда в батнике пишу:

G:\usr\local\mysql-5.5\bin\mysql.exe -u root

source code.sql

Он просто запускает mysql и не выполняет source code.sql

Comment: source - это команда клиента. Надо ему ещё сказать, что её надо выполнить - см. ключик `--execute` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

Comment: Уже нашел: G:\usr\local\mysql-5.5\bin\mysql.exe -u root diplome < code.sql

Comment: Или G:\usr\local\mysql-5.5\bin\mysql.exe -u root < code.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как создать дамп БД "pochta"

Используйте mysqldump. [Мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html).

> Как сделать автоматическое создание дампа в директорию c:\ каждый день в 2 часа ночи.

Настройте задание планировщика операционной системы.

> Как реализовать запрос "Source comand.sql" в отдельный comand.bat

Запускайте клиента командной строки, передавая ему команду в ключе *--execute*. [Мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute).

Либо просто загоняйте файл в клиента через стандартный ввод - см. там же, пример 2.

Comment: То что это mysqldump я понял, а вот синтаксис не нашел, не могли бы вы написать пример

Comment: Ну первый же пример в мануале! Если нужна аутентификация, то добавить ключи --user и --password, например `mysqldump.exe --user=pupkin@localhost --password=superpASS pochta > c:\dumps\pochta.sql`

Comment: Оказалось в денвере нету этой штуковины

Comment: Возьмите из инсталлятора community-сервера той же версии, делов-то...